# PHP Include <head> and Social Media tags

Tags: php, meta

I created a family website.  I have the header for the entire site all the way through my main as a PHP INCLUDE.  This is a must because I have a massive directory of fly down menus that need to change across the site when I change that one file.

Everything works beautifully except for one thing: I have unique articles where only on those pages I need unique meta tag OG information specific to that one page so the correct information is displayed when the article is shared on Facebook, Twitter, etc.  When you use a PHP include across the entire site for the header, how do you change the unique meta OG data for select pages only?

I know putting a 2nd head tag wouldn't be ideal.  Also, I would have to put it in the body given my include file for the header includes the top body tag.

Before I went and changed the coding logic of the site, I was hoping there is a straightforward solution to this I am no aware of (and I am a noob coder so that may be part of it).

I know I could put the main menu only in a file, and then call that menu file in a 2nd header file that is then itself called in an include across the entire site.. that would give me the latitude in those pages.  But was hoping there is an easier answer like, "oh no, they meta OG tags can go in the body like this...." or something?

Comment: You could test to see what the current page it's on and use an multi-dimensional array based on that page and then use the values from there.

Comment: Use `JavaScript` to add extra child elements `<meta ... />` in the `<head>` section of required pages.

Comment: If you are using a any cms or framework, find appropriate plugin/extension. Otherwise, if you are doing it in core PHP then you have to code it yourself in JavaScript like i briefed in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the desired header information in PHP variables at the top of the page, and **then** include the PHP header file:

**page.php**:

```
<?php
$og_url = 'http://www.example.com';
include('header.php');
?>
```

**header.php**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $og_url; ?>" />
  </head>
```

This way, you can set unique social media information for each page, while still making use of the global `<head>` section from the header file. Keep in mind that you'll probably also want fallback behaviour in case your variables aren't referenced on every page that you call the header file from:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo isset($og_url) ? $og_url : $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>" />
```

While a document has to start with `<html>`, it's perfectly fine to set PHP variables before calling `<html>`; it's only content that's actually written to the DOM that you need to worry about.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks.  Makes perfect sense.  I appreciate the responses!

Comment: No problem :) Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)